# How to monitor Nginx 500 errors and send email alerts?

Tags: linux, centos, monitoring, nginx, alert

I'd like to setup an alert system which monitors the nginx access log and sends an email alert every time it gets a 500 or 502 error. I want a simple but reliable setup but am open to all suggestions. Should I use some local scripts or remote log server? What are my options and the dis/advantages of one over the others? I'm running nginx 1.8.1 on Centos 6.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to install other software and use the tools that are already there, add since you already have rsyslog running you could configure the in ommail module

http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/ommail.html